# doFilter websocket Session and Message

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, servlet-filters, tomcat8

How do I get a WebSocket `Session` and `String` from a `request` in a `Filter`? Also, how do I determine if the request is an `Open`, `Message` or `Close` request if the request is a WebSocket request?

Assuming:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
//Session session = request.getWebSocketSession(); ??
//String string = request.getWebSocketMessage().toString(); ??
}
```

---

`Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "New request to {0}", (HttpServletRequest) request.getRequestURL().toString());`

Placing the above logging inside `doFilter` produces the following outcome upon new websocket `open` request:

`New request to http://localhost:8080/example`

Even when my Javascript is set as:

`new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090/example");`

---

After looking at the [API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsFilter.html) it seems there is a `WsFilter` but I don't see anything about `Session` or `Message`

Comment: do you mean:HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

Comment: Sure, why not. Either way...

Comment: well try it then :) it should work - get the session object like that

Comment: `getWebSocketSession()` and `getWebSocketObject()` is something I made up for illustration, I need the equivalent, except existent.

Comment: You're clearly trying to solve your problem from a wrong angle. Take a step back and tell about the problem you're trying to solve and for which you incorrectly thought that using a filter would be the right solution. Then we can answer the right solution to that. Perhaps all you need is to be able to grab the `HttpSession` inside a `@ServerEndpoint` class so that you can share some data between the websocket and some HTTP servlet based artifact? That part is in turn quite possible and I've answered that before.

Comment: @BalusC: Hey BalusC, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. It's a bit difficult to explain with a few words but here's the [source](https://github.com/ThreaT/sweven/tree/master/sweven/src/main/java/com/sweven) if you have time to look at it, specifically **Hit.java**. In short, I'm trying to redirect all requests to one method that handles all business logic the same whether requests are `HttpServletRequest`s or `WebSocket` Requests.